# Buddypress - Only allow members to access one page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, buddypress

I've searched all over and haven't been able to find a solution that works. Is it possible to block access to nonmembers for one page or a custom post type in buddypress? I have a page called Episodes that I only want buddypress members to access. Nonmembers will be redirected to the registration page. The rest of the pages on the site can be accessed by both members and nonmembers.

Answer (score 0):

by 'nonmembers' do you mean not logged in? 
Try putting this on your Episode page template:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() )
     bp_core_redirect( site_url('/register/') );
```